# Instructions after return statement in a C++ function

Tags: c++, ros

I've seen this C++ function in a ROS kobuki node ([kobuki-auto-docking](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/kobuki_auto_docking/html/auto__docking__ros_8cpp_source.html)). I wonder if the while is dead code ? Or if it can be called for a misterious reason sometimes ?

```
void AutoDockingROS::spin()
{
    return;

    while(!shutdown_requested_){;}
}
```

Thanks for your helps,

Comment: this is dead code, not reacheable.

Comment: It's clearly dead code. It seems like a programmer has added `return;` to fix a bug or something (maybe `spin` was being called inadvertently), and just left that in the codebase. (The intent of the function is clearly to *spin* until shutdown)

Comment: Maybe as safeguard in case the return would fail ? (Just kidding.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, nothing after `return` is executed.

But, you should always respect the code you see in front of you:

1. If the preprocessor `#define`s `return` to something else for a particularly odd build configuration then the code *could* run.
2. Someone might be porting the code blindly to Java. In Java, code within a `finally` block *does* run after a `return`.
3. It's possible the developer retained the line to test the syntactic validity of `!shutdown_requested_`

All unlikely scenarios (I have seen the first one in production by the way) but worth checking if you're going to undertake a large refactoring effort.

Comment: Thanks Bathsheba for your answer.
Actually, I was wondering if there is any possibilities to execute this part of the code. It doesn't seems to be one of your scenarios but I will keep them in mind. Thanks !

Comment: Would be cool if you could give us the name of that "production" to know what to stay away from.

Comment: It's open source code for ROS framework. The link is available in the question: [here](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/kobuki_auto_docking/html/auto__docking__ros_8cpp_source.html) or on [github](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/blob/indigo/kobuki_auto_docking/src/auto_docking_ros.cpp)

Answer (score 3):

Everything after a `return` statement is never going to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to this:

```
void AutoDockingROS::spin()
{
    return;

    // while(!shutdown_requested_){;}
}
```

Effectively, the programmer wanted to leave some code there, perhaps as a reminder.  It is never executed.

Answer (score 2):

No one can call code after the return... Well maybe only Chuck Norris can...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be executed after the `return` statement until its within a condition. Put the code above the `return` statement.